# JQuery mobile getting info from data tag

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
            echo <<<_END
           <pre>
           <a href="#home" data-rel="dialog" data-num="$row[1]" data-id="myid">$row[1]</a>
           </pre>
           _END;

            <script>
    var b = $('a#myid').data('num');
    document.write(b);
    </script>
```

How do I get data-num info from the tag when the link has been followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add '`=`' between attribute's name and value:

```
 <a href="#home" data-rel="dialog" data-num="$row[1]">$row[1]</a>
 //                                        ^---here it is
```

and then retrieve it like this:

```
$('a').data('num')
```

Comment: @user1546650 Probably you have multiple `a` tags, and `$('a').data('num')` returns the data of first matched `a` element. Set some `id` on appropriate `a`, and then try `$('a#myid').data('num')`

Comment: @user1546650 Can you provide(edit your question) exact part of your markup(related to `a` tag, probably some `id` is added on it), and the part when you're trying to get `data-num` .

Comment: have done I think - sorry new to jquery mobile and php and my book doesnt touch on this

Comment: @user1546650 Sorry, when you had written "have done", I had thought you resolve your problems. Ok, I see that you still have not added `=` sign between `data-num` and `"$row[1]"`.So do it. When I said add `id` on `a` tag, I dont mean `data-id`, I meant simply `id`-> `<a id="mydiv" ...`.So fix it. And put your javascript inside of `$(document).ready(function(){ your code });` callback.